# Solve issues with Wine and x3daudio1_7.dll?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I am attempting to run a Killing Floor 2 Server on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with wine version 1.7.38 as well as winetricks.

However, when I attempt to run the server I get this error:

```
wine: Call from 0x7b8491d1 to unimplemented function x3daudio1_7.dll.X3DAudioInitialize, aborting
wine: Unimplemented function x3daudio1_7.dll.X3DAudioInitialize called at address 0x7b8491d1 (thread 0025), starting debugger...
```

I assume this error is because I do not have the proper version of directX installed.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Noah Parker